# What does `function(*=)` imply in a JSDoc-style code comment?

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc

I'm writing some code comments using JSDoc style, and want to know what `*=` implies in `@returns {function(*=): *}`, which is generated by WebStorm.

I have tried to search the JSDoc wiki and usejsdoc.org but with no result.

Below is my code:

```
/**
 * Get record data listener generator.
 * @param {Function} createProps
 * @returns {function(*=): *}        // ** generated by webstorm **
 */
export function getRecordCustomDataListener(createProps) {
  return (callback) => onRecordCustomData({ createRecordData: createProps })(callback); // `onRecordCustomData` has not default argument
}
```

I want to know what `*=` implies in `@returns {function(*=): *}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**See edit at the bottom!!**

Testing it in WebStorm with a small snippet seems to indicate that `*=` means a parameter is **not** optional and can be of any type where `*` indicates that the parameter is of any type and optional. See the following example with generated jsdoc from WebStorm:

```
/**
 *
 * @param createProps
 * @returns {function(*=, *): void}
 */
export function a(createProps) {
    return (callback, callback2) => console.log(callback);
}
```

As you can see we are only using the first parameter `callback` and leave `callback2` unused. Webstorm generates the proper jsdoc for that.

The full jsdoc for our example above in english words: `Return an arrow function that takes two parameters, a **not** optional first parameter that can be of any type, and an optional second parameter that can be of any type. That function returns void`

Docs reference:

http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html

**Optional parameter**

> An optional parameter named foo.
>
> @param {number} [foo]
>
> // or:
>
> @param {number=} foo
>
> An optional parameter foo with default value 1.
>
> @param {number} [foo=1]

---

**EDIT:** The docs indicate that `=` means `optional parameter` but webstorm generates it with the opposite meaning. Either its wrongly documented or WebStorm does it wrong. I have tested it in WebStorm 2018.1
Build #WS-181.4203.535, built on March 22, 2018

Comment: Do you have the link to the doc where you found this? Thanks.

Comment: @Armel I have added another edit because my observations with webstorm are not what the jsdoc documentation states.